# In oreo 8.1.0 I cant get fcm device id

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.1-oreo

I am using vivo v9 android 8.1.0 oreo. i cant find device id

my config:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
```

class path :

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
```

Comment: -What have you tried?

Comment: actually in my device not getting push notificaiton so i update message and core ,playservice version...after that i checked device id getting empty .. my MyFirebaseInstanceIDService class not execute..

Comment: if suppose downgrade version na device id getting value but  while push notification received time this method (onMessageReceived) not execute .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually we need to this dependencies
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'

And We need to create a Channel in FCM messaging class.

Answer (score 1):

In Latest Firebase they change the method to get the Device Token.

Kindly follow the code where you want the ID

```
  FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(LoginPageActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
 @Override
        public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
            Log.e("Device Token",instanceIdResult.getToken());
        }
    });
```